# How to store a large java object on some kind of server

Tags: java, mysql, json, google-app-engine, serialization

I currently have the following issue:

I am looking for a proper way to store a large java object on some kind of server, which could be a MySQL database or Google App Engine. I have found a lot of ways to 'store' an object, but I am looking for some advice what's best in this case:

**Case**

I have created some sort of shop management system for small businesses. Users of the app can generate reports about e.g. sales. I want to create the functionality to save these reports, such that they can be generated later in time, without setting all the options for it again.

**Class**

The layout of the `Report` class can be found below (I have excluded the getters, setters and list operators):

```
public class Report {

    /* ATTRIBUTES */

    public IntegerProperty ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public Employee employee = null;
    public BooleanProperty timeFilterPresent = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public StringProperty optionalBasicFilterStatement = new SimpleStringProperty();

    /* Categories */

    public ReportCategory category;
    public ReportSubcategory subCategory;

    /* Filters */

    public List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Views */

    public List<ReportView> views = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<VBox> generatedViews = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Queries */

    public List<Query> queries = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Time intervals */

    public List<TimeInterval> timeIntervals = new ArrayList<>();
```

As you can see, this is a pretty large class. All of the other classes that are mentioned in the `Report` class, are also custom made (such as `Filter`, `Employee`, `ReportCategory` etc).

**Options to store the object**

I have found the following options for saving this object:

1. **Make the class `Serializable`, convert the object to a byte array and store it in a MySQL database**

   I have tried this, but it would be a lot of work to make all the sub-classes `Serializable` as well, and I am not even sure if this would work properly in this case.
2. **Use `Gson` to convert the object to `JSON`, and store this in a MySQL database as plain text**

   When I just try this without any tweaking, I get a StackOverflow error. I could create a custom Json-Converter for this class, but then I would need to do this for every subclass too. Also, I would have to make a converter from `JSON` to an object.
3. **Store object on Google App Engine, by also defining the necessary classes there**

   I would have to duplicate all the classes on the Google App Engine, which is not practical when I change in the class or some of the subclasses is made. I could serve the object as a `Blob` to my application.
4. **Create MySQL tables for these classes**

   I could create separate tables for these classes, but then I need to create a lot of tables for only one single usage.

All of these options have their (dis-)advantages, and because I do not have any experience with storing java objects, I would like to know if I am missing any options and which of the options you prefer. All of these options take some time to implement, so I want to be sure to choose the correct one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/save-serializable-object-in-java/

Comment: Why not simply have a DB Report table with columns that has foreign key references to values from other tables (linked to their primary key)?

Comment: you forgot about important disadvantage of Serializable - you cannot deserialize to a new version of same class (at most cases), so you'll be unable to develop your categories/filters/etc further. PS actually you can make minor improvements, etc, maybe some new fields, but it will make a problem at some point most likely

Comment: @Igor: yes forgott that. thx for the hint

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I could do that, thanks for mentioning that. Keep in mind that one table would not be sufficient: I have to create multiple tables to cover all the used classes.

Comment: That's the reason for having a DB: It's relational. The relationship will exist and the DB is optimized to manage it.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I decided to create the MySQL databases, which was some work, but it works perfectly. Thanks for your opinion, which I would like to credit you for, but I don't know how..

Comment: It's ok. I hope that your choice really solves your dilemma and good luck in your project. :-)